# cgi script is not executing

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a `perl.cgi` file which has the content:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<h1>Hello World</h1>\n";
```

I made it executable. (`chmod a+x perl.cgi`)

Then I created a new file `perl.htm` in the same directory. Which has the following data:

```
Content-type: text/html
<p><a href="perl.cgi">RUN perl.cgi</a></p>
```

When I run the `perl.htm` in my browser then I get the output as:

```
Content-type: text/html
RUN perl.cgi
```

When I click on `RUN perl.cgi` another page opens and there the output is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<h1>Hello World</h1>\n";
```

i.e. the `perl.cgi` is not executing. Only the file contents are being shown.

**EDIT:** From the answers and comments I came to know that I will have to configure my web server (apache) to run cgi scripts. How can I do that? Let me know.

Comment: You need to describe your web server setup in far more detail.

Comment: Voted to move to http://serverfault.com but ... try renaming the file to 'perl.pl'. If that's not it you need to configure your webserver corectly for executing perl cgi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem has been solved. I was not using httpd service at all, was opening from file:// URL.

[Perl script is not executing in HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669609/perl-script-is-not-executing-in-html-form)

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like Apache is not configured to run *.cgi files:

```
AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
<Directory /path/to/cgi/files>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Comment: Done, still having the same problem

Comment: I am still unable to run cgi. Please help.

Comment: @Chankey Pathak have you read the documentation?  Apache configuration is hairy, it pays off to study it in detail.

Comment: Chankey Pathak: What error is in log files? If you copied it from Windows, fif you transfer it in text mode?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you are loading the CGI module in the httpd.conf file:

`LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so` or 
`LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgid.so` depending on which version of Apache you are running.

You can also read about additional solutions for 
[Dynamic Content with CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your web server so that it executes *.cgi files (or, more normally, all the files in a particular directory) rather than just delivering them to the browser as it does .html files.

How this is done depends on your server.

Comment: I am using apache. How can I configure it to be able to run cgi?

Comment: See the answer from @Gabriel and maybe add ScriptAliasMatch ^/cgi-bin(.*) "/full/path/to/cgi/directory/$1" in your <IfModule alias_module> section