# Perl script is not executing in HTML form

Tags: perl, apache

I have a `guestbook.htm` file in the directory named as Chrome (/home/chankey/Desktop/Chrome/guestbook.htm) whose content is given below

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Guestbook</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/home/chankey/Desktop/Chrome/guestbook.pl" method="get">
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td><input name="name" type="text" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td>E-Mail</td><td><input name="email" type="text" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td>Location</td><td><input name="loc" type="text" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td>Comments</td><td>
<TEXTAREA name="comments" rows="10" cols="32"></TEXTAREA></td></tr>
</table><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Add Entry">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

In the same Chrome directory I have one file "guestbook.pl" whose content is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $query_string = "";
#Get the input
if ($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq 'POST') {
read(STDIN, $query_string, $ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH});
} else {
$query_string = $ENV{QUERY_STRING};
}
##### We will remove this
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print "Query String is \n<br> $query_string";
##### We will remove this
```

When I am executing the guestbook.htm file there appears a form, when I fill the data and click on "Add Entry" button a new page opens where the complete script appears.

i.e. the script "guestbook.pl" is not executing. May I know the reason behind this? Why the script is not executing? (I have already given executing permission to this file).

In the httpd.conf file I have added

```
AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
<Directory /home/chankey/Desktop/Chrome/>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Still it is not executing. Let me know the reason.

Comment: Are you actually accessing this through your web server (over HTTP), or are you trying to access it from the filesystem (with a `file://` URL)?

Comment: Oops I am using file:///home/chankey/Desktop/Chrome/guestbook.htm

Comment: Refer this url http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=44536

Comment: I'm using Linux, Devendra. Problem has been solved btw :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you access a file locally (over the `file://` type URL in your browser), it's not running from a web server, so:

- There is no CGI environment
- The `httpd.conf`/`.htaccess` files have no effect

A few ways to deal with this:

- Create a folder named `public_html` in your home. Your web server likely has a setting to map `http://localhost/~chankey/` to `/home/chankey/public_html`. (On MacOSX, the preferred name is `Sites`, instead, I believe.) On an SELinux system, you'll have to specifically grant permission for Apache to use this method.
- For the specific case of Perl scripts using the standard `CGI` package, you can also run them manually from a terminal shell, and redirect their output to a temporary file (e.g. `>/tmp/output.html`), which you can then access
- Migrate your development workspace into your web server's own directory structure, typically `/var/www/html/`…

PS / unrelated: I strongly recommend that, if you plan to put this on the Internet, you should probably `use CGI; use strict;` and have the tainting mode enabled `#!/usr/bin/perl -WT` …

Comment: I'd give two more upvotes for the "unrelated" if it were possible!

Comment: :-) yeah, I'm a tainting Nazi. It's the #1 thing I miss from Perl in *any* other language.

Comment: Yes, I just had to move htm file to /var/www/html and script file to cgi-bin/ and it worked. Thank you :)

Comment: There's no reason to add `use CGI` to a script that doesn't use anything from CGI.pm — and I wouldn't recommend writing new code to use CGI.pm :)

Comment: Why would not recommend using CGI.pm? — given the code above, I would 100% recommend rewriting it to use CGI.pm … it's already subject to multiple security exploits, and it doesn't do anything, yet.

Comment: @BRPocock because it could just as easily be rewritten as a tiny PSGI app, allowing it to run under CGI, FastCGI, mod_perl, standalone webservers, etc. and gaining compatibility with lots of nice debugging tools, among other things.

Comment: CGI.pm does that, as well, and is in the standard distribution… but I will have to look into this PSGI, hadn't run across it before. (I don't do a lot of web-facing stuff, actually.)